# How To Control Column Name in JSON Parsing?

Tags: android, json

I want to JSON Parsing in Android. But, I had a problem when I am parsing.

This problem is, sometimes I haven't a column in my JSON.

Normally JSON Object:

```
 {
     "name":"A",
     "surname":"B",
     "age":"1",
     "mail":"C"
  },
```

Anormally JSON Object:

```
  {
     "name":"A",
     "surname":"B",
     "age":"1",
  },
```

When I don't have "mail" column, my app is crashing. How I control name of column when I parse JSON? Example, if I haven't mail column, I want set default a string value.

```
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(URL);
  JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObj.getJSONArray("members");

  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject m = member.getJSONObject(i);              
      Name = m.optString("name");
      Surname = m.getString("surname");
      Age = m.getString("age");
      Mail = m.getString("mail");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a default value: `getString(key, defaultValue)`

Change `m.getString("mail")`

to

```
m.getString("mail", "defaultValue")
```

In case there is no email your ouput will be e.g.:

```
{
     "name":"A",
     "surname":"B",
     "age":"1",
     "email": "defaultValue"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check using m.has()

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(URL);
            JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObj.getJSONArray("members");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject m = member.getJSONObject(i);
               String Name = m.optString("name");
                String Surname = m.getString("surname");
                String Age = m.getString("age");
                if(m.has("mail")) {
                    String Mail = m.getString("mail");
                }
```